# long processing jobs in a java web app

Tags: java, asynchronous, web

What is the best way to perform long tasks (triggered by a user and for that user only) in a java web app? I tried using ejb @Asynchronous and jax-ws asynchronous (polling) calls but the Future<?> they are returning is not serializable and could not be stored in HttpSession (to retrieve the result later when it's done). Is there a simple way to use concurrent Future<?> in a java web environment or do I have to go with a full-blown jobs management framework?

Comment: why has the Future<?> to be serializable? do you want to persist your session?

Comment: in our environment, sessions are aggressively persisted to disk due to the great number of users. I could however store the Futures in a Map<HttpSession, List<Future<?>>> in a static field or in applicationScope (ServletContext) + cleanup through an HttpSessionListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solution so far was to use an application-scoped Map<SessionId, List<Future<?>>>. This works in cluster with sticky sessions and does not need to use JMS queues and storage of result in database.

Answer (score 2):

The best is to use JMS . Implement a messaging solution which is asynchronous which sends a message to a queue/topic where a MDB listens to that queue / topic to be triggered upon the message arrival to perform the long task in an offline manner

http://www.javablogging.com/simple-guide-to-java-message-service-jms-using-activemq/

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/

Comment: The problem using JMS is that it's not enough on its own, I'll need to store some Job description (userid/sessionid, input parameters, result?) in a database: it begins to look like a jobs management system. What I would like is HttpSession-scoped jobs: create a Callable, send it to an executor, receive a handle that I can store in HttpSession and query for completion/result later. If the user logs-out then all his jobs are lost (I don't need and don't want the jobs to be persisted in a database)

Answer (score 1):

If your process is supposed to generate a result and you are expecting the process to take a long time, probably the best way is two have 2 separate calls:

1. First one to trigger the process and which return a unique process identifier
2. Second one to retrieve the result using the process identifier

So your overall process flow will be:

1. Client call back end service.
2. Back end service starts async process with unique id and return the unique id to client right away.
3. Async process persist the result in session or other more persistent mechanism (db, file, etc.)
4. Client side poll server with unique id
5. Retrieval method return result when exist, otherwise return *not done* message